# NameError: uninitialized constant SvgGenerator (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

was updating a rails app to 7.1.3 and when I run 'rails zeitwerk:check' I got this error message.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant SvgGenerator (NameError)

parent.const_get(cname, false)
       ^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `const_get'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `cget'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:175:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:40:in `block in ls'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:170:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:379:in `block in eager_load_all'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:377:in `each'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.13/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:377:in `eager_load_all'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/zeitwerk_checker.rb:6:in `check'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/tasks/zeitwerk.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:182:in `invoke_task'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `each'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:138:in `block in top_level'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:147:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:132:in `top_level'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:208:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:27:in `block in perform'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:44:in `block in with_rake'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:59:in `with_application'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:41:in `with_rake'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:156:in `invoke_rake'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:73:in `block in invoke'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:149:in `with_argv'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/command.rb:69:in `invoke'
/Users/dmorin/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => zeitwerk:check
```

Here is the the beginning of my svg_generator.rb file that is located in lib/rails_admin/config/actions folder

```
require 'rails_admin/config/actions'
require 'rails_admin/config/actions/base'

module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class SvgGenerator < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)

        register_instance_option :member? do
        true
      end
      ...
```

And I use it in rails_admin.rb file this way

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/svg_generator"

RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.asset_source = :sprockets

  ### Popular gems integration

  # == Devise ==
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  # == Cancan ==
  config.authorize_with :cancancan

  ## == Pundit ==
  # config.authorize_with :pundit

  ## == PaperTrail ==
  config.audit_with :paper_trail, 'User', 'PaperTrail::Version' # PaperTrail >= 3.0.0

  ### More at https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Base-configuration

  ## == Gravatar integration ==
  ## To disable Gravatar integration in Navigation Bar set to false
  # config.show_gravatar true

  config.main_app_name = ['CHU de Québec - Plans Interactifs', 'Admin']

  PAPER_TRAIL_AUDIT_MODEL = %w(Point Portal Path)
  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app
    nestable

    svg_generator do
      visible do
        'Hospital' == bindings[:abstract_model].model_name
      end
    end

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    history_index do
      only PAPER_TRAIL_AUDIT_MODEL
    end
    history_show do
      only PAPER_TRAIL_AUDIT_MODEL
    end

    config.model Floor do
      nestable_list({
        position_field: :index
      })
    end
  end
end
```

Is somebody can see what is wrong with this class?

Comment: Maybe the SvgGenerator class isn't loaded correctly? You can try adding the lib directory to the autoload paths by adding ```config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)``` to config/application.rb then restart your Rails server

Comment: The Class Name is `RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::SvgGenerator`. I am not certain where the error is coming from becuase you did not post a full stack trace but right not it appears it is trying to look up the constant `::SvgGenerator` (which does not exist).

Comment: @engineersmnky I have added the full debug trace

Comment: If you're running Rails 7.1, you should ditch the `require` statement in rails_admin.rb and make sure you are using the `autoload_lib` config: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-autoload-lib-and-config-autoload-lib-once

Comment: @LukeAbel now running the commande zeitwerk:check give me this error:

NoMethodError: undefined method `svg_generator' for RailsAdmin::Config::Actions:Module (NoMethodError)

    svg_generator do
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: It seems like you're trying to do what's in this blog post: https://blog.snajdr.de/custom-actions-for-rails-admin-cf88c2a704b4

I would do what he is doing there and put this class in `config/initializers` instead of `lib`.

Comment: Is `lib` or any of its subdirectories in the autoload paths? (`bin/rails r 'pp ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths`'). Was this working untouched before the upgrade? Upgrading from which version?

Comment: Could you also please throw `Rails.autoloaders.log!` in `config/application.rb` and share the log?